# What does wildcard mean in makefile?

Tags: makefile

I found the following lines in a makefile tutorial, but I have some problem with the bold lines.

In 1 line, if I write

```
program_C_SRCS:=$(*.c)
```

it does not work. So please tell me what is 
wildcard word in doing here. Is this word is specific to the makefile only?

In tutorial it is written that second line will perform the test substitution. Can anyone tell me something about this text substitution?

Please excuse me if my questions are very basic because I am new to make filestuff.

[link of tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/how-to-write-a-makefile)

```
CC:=g++
program_NAME:=myprogram
**program_C_SRCS:=$(wildcard *.c)**  # 1 line 
program_CXX_SRCS:=$(wildcard *.cc)
**program_C_OBJ:=$(program_C_SRCS:.c=.o)** # 2 line
program_CXX_OBJ:=$(program_CXX_SRCS:.c=.o)
program_OBJ:= $(program_C_OBJ) $(program_CXX_OBJ)
```

Comment: Links appears to be broken.

Comment: @jghfun-run http://web.archive.org/web/20110503093716/https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/how-to-write-a-makefile

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Suppose you have two source files. `foo.c` and `bar.c`.

```
program_C_SRCS:=$(wildcard *.c) # 1 line
```

The `wildcard` function is Make syntax. The variable `program_C_SRCS` will now have the value `foo.c bar.c` (maybe not in that order).

```
program_C_OBJ:=$(program_C_SRCS:.c=.o) # 2 line
```

This is a [substitution reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs). It transforms text, replacing one substring with another. The variable `program_C_OBJ` now has the value `foo.o bar.o`.

Answer (score 3):

The use of wildcard card function in make file is to list all the source files with a particular extension. For example:

```
program_C_SRCS:=$(*.c) // In this the variable program_C_SRCS will have all the files with ".c" extension.
```

Suppose if you want to convert `.c` files to `.o` files then the following syntax may be useful:

```
program_C_OBJS:=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))
```